# Google CloudSQL - How to remove remove superuser permissions created by terraform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

I am creating cloudsql user using terraform .

```
resource "google_sql_user" "postgresql" {
  for_each = toset(var.db_user_name)
  name     = each.value
  project  = var.app_project
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.postgresql.name
  password = var.db_user_password
}
```

It creates user but with `Create role, Create DB` roles and a member of `cloudsqlsuperuser`. I want to create BuildIn user only not with IAM user or IAM service account. Can we revoke these roles and membership later using below resource. If not with postgresql provider , can this be achieved with `community.postgresql.postgresql_privs` ansible module.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    postgresql = {
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = ">=1.4.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "postgresql" {
  #scheme           = "gcppostgres"
  host             = var.postgres_host
  username         = "postgres"
  password         = "pass"
  superuser        = false
  expected_version = "10.1"
  alias            = "postgres"
}
resource "postgresql_grant" "readwrite" {
  provider    = postgresql.postgres
  for_each    = { for role in var.roles : "${role.role}-${role.database}-${role.object_type}-${role.schema}" => role if role.object_type != "default_privs" }
  role        = each.value.role
  database    = each.value.database
  object_type = each.value.object_type
  objects     = (each.value.object_type == "database" || each.value.object_type == "schema") ? [] : each.value.objects
  schema      = each.value.schema
  privileges  = each.value.privileges
}

variable "roles" {
  type = list(object({
    role        = string
    database    = string
    object_type = string
    obj_t       = string
    objects     = list(string)
    schema      = string
    privileges  = list(string)
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user through the Cloud SQL API (which is the API used by terraform to create it) it will be always be superuser.

The only way to remove superuser permissions or in any case create a user with custom permissions is by logging to the DB and create there the user so yes, using `community.postgresql.postgresql_privs` could be a good idea.

Comment: Followup question - should I just create the permissions by ansible module ```community.postgresql.postgresql_privs``` , but in that case I'll have to remove the superuser privilages , is that possible with the module ```community.postgresql.postgresql_privs``` . Or I should create both users and role permissions with the ansible module.